# Regular expression for nested C structs

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regex to solve the below C struct 
for one of our requirement.
I am parsing the C structure file. In that I will have child and parent struct. The child will inherit parent struct members. I want the output, which consists of struct members and there length for further processing

INPUT:

```
#define  Len1  10;
#define  Len2  20;
#define  Len3   3;
#define  Len4   4;

typedef struct
{
char CHAR1           [Len1];
char CHAR2           [Len2];
} MyParent;


typedef struct
{

MyParent base;
char CHAR3        [Len3];
char CHAR4          [Len4];

} MyChild;
```

In the above I have to get: below OUTPUT:

```
 CHAR1 10
 CHAR2 20
 CHAR3 3
 CHAR4 4
```

The Perl Script will be really helpfull;

Comment: You have given an input and output, but you haven't said exactly what you want to do. do you want a regex to parse declarators? do you want it to extract eg `char uppercase(char i);`?

Comment: What is that you are looking for? array declarations? Variable declarations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed the problem after I gave my answer. It's not big of a deal though because the answer is not that much more complicated. You remember what you see in the `#define`s and use them later:

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    if( /^#define\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)/ ) {
        $Len{$1} = $2;
        }
    elsif( /^char\s/ ){
        s/(?<=CHAR\d)\s+//;
        s/;$//;
        s/(?<=\[)(\w+)(?=])/ $Len{$1} || $1 /e;
        print;
        }
    }
```

---

This is a pretty trivial problem. Are you sure there's something that you aren't telling us? You don't need to do anything fancy. Skip all the lines that you want to ignore, and fixup the remaining lines to match your output needs:

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    next unless /^char\s/;
    s/(?<=CHAR\d)\s+//;
    s/;$//;
    print;
    }

__DATA__
#define  Len1  10;
#define  Len2  20;
#define  Len3   3;
#define  Len4   4;

typedef struct
{
char CHAR1           [Len1];
char CHAR2           [Len2];
} MyBase;


typedef struct
{

MyBase base;
char CHAR3          [Len3];
char CHAR4          [Len4];

} MyStruct;
```

Comment: I imagine the OP wants more, but since he's not telling us what, this is the best he'll get :)

Comment: Sorry for not giving the complete requirement:
I am parsing the C structure file.
In that I will have child and parent struct.
The child will inherit parent struct members.

I want the output, which consists of struct members and 
there length for further processing.

I have edited the OUTPUT as the exact need
Thanks all for quick reply

Comment: @user430294:  If this is not all you need, then regular expressions are not what you are looking for; you would need a real parser.

Comment: Upvoted, for being a good original answer. brain d foy++ (this time)

Answer (score 2):

What about this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %len;
while( <DATA> ) {
    if (/^#define\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s*;/) {
        $len{$1} = $2;
    } elsif (s/^\s*char\s+(\w+)\s+\[(\w+)\]\s*;/$1 $len{$2}/) {
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
#define  Len1  10;
#define  Len2  20;
#define  Len3   3;
#define  Len4   4;

typedef struct
{
char CHAR1           [Len1];
char CHAR2           [Len2];
} MyBase;


typedef struct
{

MyBase base;
char CHAR3          [Len3];
char CHAR4          [Len4];

} MyStruct;
```

output :

```
CHAR1 10
CHAR2 20
CHAR3 3
CHAR4 4
```

Comment: I am really glad that I am getting quick reply's in this forum.    Thanks a lot for all. <:0)

Comment: Who did he copy? Don't accuse people without proof because you're retaliating because you're mad that M42 bested you in another question.